# Jquery Mobile pagecontainershow event not firing in emulator, but is on device?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, android-emulator, jquery-events

I have two event listeners `pagecontainerbeforeshow` and `pagecontainershow`, but both only fire when code is deployed to my Android devices (Nexus 6P, and the oldie Nexus S). When I launch the code in the Android Emulator (Nougat), the code doesn't fire, and there are no error messages.

MWE code snippet:

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function(event, ui) {
    console.log('I AM HERE');
});
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').on('pagecontainershow', function(event, ui) {
    console.log('I AM HERE 2');
});
```

What's weird is that I have other identical code (for other modularity needs) elsewhere in the project (but still loaded from the same DOM) which fires fine. Internally the other code uses a switch to differentiate specific pages (`switch (ui.toPage.attr('id')) {`), again its identical except for content of the event fired callback.

I can't figure out why everything works when deployed to a device, including a very old device such as a Nexus S, but it doesn't when deployed to an emulator.

It doesn't break. The `pagecontainershow` and `pagecontainerbeforeshow` simply doesn't get triggered.

Could it be something along the lines that the original page show events are consuming the event?

Any ideas?

Notes:

- Jquery Mobile version: jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js

Comment: maybe too late, but i believe anyway you can find somewhat useful also for the 1.5.0 alpha there: [PageContainer Events](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/tag/pagecontainer-events/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - thanks deblocker.

**tl;dr**: Add the event listeners after the DOM ready event - in my case check for both DOM ready, and Cordova device ready.

```
$(function() { // DOM Ready
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

// Cordova device ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  $(':mobile-pagecontainer').on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function(event, ui) {
    // This now works correctly
  }
}
```

---

### Cause

In my case, I wrongly interpreted the [Cordova deviceready event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready), which says "*However, JavaScript only loads once the DOM loads*". I read this to mean that listening to the `deviceready` event would implicitly mean that the DOM is also ready - this is not the case.

---

### Previous workaround

Change the Jquery selector to `document`:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforeshow', function (event, ui) {
    console.log('I AM WORKING 1');
});
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function(event, ui) {
    console.log('I AM WORKING 2');
});
```

Now, all events are fired on my devices and in the Android emulator.

This works because document is available before the rest of the DOM is ready.

Comment: maybe too early? where did you put the `$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on...` handler ? you can't attach an event handler to the pagecontainer if it wasn't already instantiated.

Comment: This would not be the case, otherwise it would still not be working after changing the jQuery selector to 'document'.

Comment: try this: put your first code `$(':mobile-pagecontainer').on...` in a button click handler on your landing  page,  click the button.and see what happen. just guessing: you had that code in domready?

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, was indeed to do with the DOM ready - read the 'cause' in the updated answer.
Thanks :)